# how pass array in postgresql function

Tags: postgresql, function

i am trying to pass an text array in pg function but i am facing different errors please help me how i pass an array which have different data type as text and integer.... my code here

```
CREATE or replace FUNCTION get_data(text[])
RETURNS TABLE(sheet_no text,type text,road_name text,lon text,lat text) 
AS $$  
DECLARE 
sql text;
 BEGIN 
        sql ='set session "myapp.user" ='||$1;
        execute  sql;

        update tbl_encroachment
        set landuse = $2 
        where tbl_encroachment.unique_land_parcel_no = $3
        and tbl_encroachment.parcel_sub_division = $4;  

        RETURN QUERY 
        select foo.sheet_no,foo.type,foo.road_name,foo.lon,foo.lat
        from tbl_encroachment as foo
        where foo.unique_land_parcel_no = $3
        and foo.parcel_sub_division = $4;
        RETURN;        

 end
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

--execute query     
select sheet_no,type,road_name,lon,lat from get_data('{7,hasilpur,7-35-251-0001_1-1-9-SUK_001,9}'::text[])
```

Comment: facing error : ERROR:  malformed array literal: "set session "myapp.user" ="
LINE 1: SELECT 'set session "myapp.user" ='||$1

Answer (score 1):

You can't access array elements like that. `$1` represents whole array, so you need to do something like `$1[1], $1[2], $1[3]` instead of `$1, $2, $3`

So try this:

```
CREATE or replace FUNCTION get_data(text[])
RETURNS TABLE(sheet_no text,type text,road_name text,lon text,lat text) 
AS $$  
DECLARE 
sql text;
 BEGIN 
        sql ='set session "myapp.user" ='||$1[1];
        execute  sql;

        update tbl_encroachment
        set landuse = $1[2]
        where tbl_encroachment.unique_land_parcel_no = $1[3]
        and tbl_encroachment.parcel_sub_division = $1[4];  

        RETURN QUERY 
        select foo.sheet_no,foo.type,foo.road_name,foo.lon,foo.lat
        from tbl_encroachment as foo
        where foo.unique_land_parcel_no = $1[3]
        and foo.parcel_sub_division = $1[4];
        RETURN;        

 end
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use [format](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html) for dynamic sql. **(updated to reflect OP comment)**

> type (required)
>
> The type of format conversion to use to produce the format specifier's
>   output. The following types are supported:
>
> - s formats the argument value as a simple string. A null value is treated as an empty string.
> - I treats the argument value as an SQL identifier, double-quoting it if necessary. It is an error for the value to be null (equivalent to
>     quote_ident).
> - L quotes the argument value as an SQL literal. A null value is displayed as the string NULL, without quotes (equivalent to
>     quote_nullable).

change

```
 sql ='set session "myapp.user" ='||$1;
        execute  sql;
```

to

```
 sql =format('set session "myapp.user" = %L',$1);
        execute  sql;
```

here's working example:

```
t=# SELECT current_setting('myapp.user');
ERROR:  unrecognized configuration parameter "myapp.user"
Time: 0.305 ms
t=# do
t-# $$
t$# begin
t$#   execute format ('set session "myapp.user" = %L','try it');
t$# end;
t$# $$
t-# ;
DO
Time: 0.337 ms
t=# SELECT current_setting('myapp.user');
 current_setting
-----------------
 try it
(1 row)
```

Comment: @user2638158 quotes the argument value as an SQL literal.